# A globe from a torch and a refrigerator bulb are connected in series across a power supply. Predict what would happen?

Tags: voltage, circuit-design

A globe from a torch (rated at 6V, 0.5 amp) and a refrigerator bulb (rated 240V, 10W) are connected in series across a 240V power supply. Predict what would happen?

I understand that the torch globe will emit very little light and the other globe will operate normally but I don't understand why? Would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Try to calculate the resistance of each individual bulbs (simply by assuming that the bulb resistance is constant which is not true). And apply the voltage divider rule.

Comment: possibly "translated" from NZ or Australian :)

Comment: Yes, I am a little Australian student :) When you say voltage divider, you mean voltage drops?

Comment: @JorenVaes - what country are you in? Globe is a well enough known term internationally. | The great and awesome Philips corporation started as a light globe maker named "Philips glow lamp maker" or in Dutch Philips Gloeilampenfabrieken. I suspect (but may be wrong) that Globe derives from Gloeil... . But, globe is a term used for a sphere on some contexts. 
https://wiki2.org/en/Philips+Brights

Comment: Fwiw - this shows  the frequency of occurence  of "light globe" in English since about 880. 
 "light bulb" is over 100 times more used :-).
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=light+globe&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clight%20globe%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I learned a new word today. Up to this point I never heard the term "light globe', and could imagine this being a mis-translation (as globe/sphere/bulb might have synonymous terms in other languages). I stand corrected, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @JorenVaes It's great to learn new things serendipitously. I suspect that I've fallen below the fabled "one new thing bnefore breakfast every day" but still soak up all I may.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by calculating the operating resistance of the two bulbs.

Given V = IxR, the torch bulb will have a resistance of about 12 ohms.

Given P = V^2/R, the refrigerator will have a resistance of about 5760 ohms.

With me so far? Now let's look at the proposed circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fH4MyB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From this we can calculate the voltage across the torch bulb, and it is $$V=240\frac{12}{12+5760}=0.499 $$

So our 6 volt bulb will have about 1/2 volt across it, and will barely light up.

This is not the most accurate analysis, since (as you probably don't know) light bulbs do not have a constant resistance. Typically, when cold a bulb filament resistance will be on the order of 10 times less than when hot. In this case, that works to make the bulb even dimmer. A variation of 10:1 won't make much difference in the bulb current, since that is controlled by the 5760 ohms of the refrigerator bulb. But if the torch bulb filament resistance is 1.2 ohms rather than 12, the voltage across the bulb will only be about 0.05 volts, and the the bulb will be really, really dim. Note that this very dim condition is consistent with the low filament resistance derived by assuming the filament is cold, so it's an indication that the assumption was correct.

Comment: The (low voltage) bulb won't be just dim, it won't emity *any* visible light. It needs to heat itself above 600°C to do so - which it won't be able to at the voltag/current.

Comment: Oh, blackbodies emit radiation at _all_ frequencies, regardless of temperature. But the intensity can get, ahem, pretty small.